# cannot find roscpp when following tutorial 3

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg, roscpp, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey all,
i'm following the ROS tutorial 3 in which it teaches how to create a new package which has dependencies.
when i enter the following:
$ roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials roscpp rospy std_msgs
terminal shoots back:
ERROR: dependency [roscpp] cannot be found

note : i've updated the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable.
i have verified manually and (with rospack find also) that roscpp actually exists in my filesystem. its just that roscreate cant seem to find it.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10245/cannot-find-roscpp-when-following-tutorial-3/) by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-13**:
can you describe your install setup better? i.e. what is your ROS_ROOT, what is your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and where is roscpp? can you also verify that you can run "rospack find roscpp", then run the roscreate-pkg command and still get a failure.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-13**:
in the terminal you're trying to roscreate-pkg, can you roscd roscpp. If not your package path is not set in that terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set accordingly.

1. Close your terminal and open again which will reload your ~/.ros to default one.
2. Run the following again
   $ cd ~/
   $ mkdir ros_tutorials
   $ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_tutorials:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
3. To verify whether your PATH set correctly, try 'roscd roscpp'. If it changes to the roscpp folder then path file is set correctly.
4. Now try creating package with dependencies you wish.

Hope this would help you.
Note: I am a newbie in ROS, please let me know if there is something wrong.

---

Originally posted by [jintgeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/723/jintgeorge/) with karma: 16 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-22**:
thanks! that was precisely the problem. now I directly edit my .bashrc file instead of updating my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH everytime i open a mew terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed diamondback via deb packages, to setup your environment use:

```
. /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4